# Modal pop up window issues with JavaScript on youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I have a big issue with JavaScript pop up modal windows displaying a YouTube iframe video! I've been spending already a week or even more to find a solution to this problem, on the internet but it seems that there are not many resources or answers and/or solutions to this problem I have, so I thought I should ask for your help on this.

=========================================================================

### **THE PROBLEM:**

OK, I have an image on my offline website that when you click on it, it fires a pop up modal window in the browser, with a iframe YouTube video clip and when you click on it the YouTube video it plays as it should be. **So far so good**, all works fine until you close the window (*by clicking anywhere outside of the video or on the **X** button, as usual!*), however, the problem is that even the video closes, the sound still continues playing in the background as if the video is still there, even though the video is not as its been closed successfully.

## By the way, this issue happens on all browsers.

## This is the code, the same code you can find on the jsfiddle link below:

```
    <!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
<button id="my-button"> Play video </button>
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up"> 
        <a class="b-close"> x <a/>
        <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ev4zBCBEELQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div><!-- end of element_to_pup_up id -->
```

=========================================================================

```
    #element_to_pop_up {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    min-width:400px;
    min-height: 180px;
}
.b-close {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:5px;
}
```

=========================================================================

```
    // Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
    // Encapsulation
    // $ is assigned to jQuery
    ;
    (function ($) {

        // DOM Ready
        $(function () {

            // Binding a click event
            // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
            $('#my-button').bind('click', function (e) {

                // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                e.preventDefault();

                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

            });

        });

    })(jQuery);

(function (b) {
        b.fn.bPopup = function (z, F) {
            function K() {
                a.contentContainer = b(a.contentContainer || c);
                switch (a.content) {
                    case "iframe":
                        var h = b('<iframe class="b-iframe" ' + a.iframeAttr + "></iframe>");
                        h.appendTo(a.contentContainer);
                        r = c.outerHeight(!0);
                        s = c.outerWidth(!0);
                        A();
                        h.attr("src", a.loadUrl);
                        k(a.loadCallback);
                        break;
                    case "image":
                        A();
                        b("<img />").load(function () {
                            k(a.loadCallback);
                            G(b(this))
                        }).attr("src", a.loadUrl).hide().appendTo(a.contentContainer);
                        break;
                    default:
                        A(), b('<div class="b-ajax-wrapper"></div>').load(a.loadUrl, a.loadData, function () {
                            k(a.loadCallback);
                            G(b(this))
                        }).hide().appendTo(a.contentContainer)
                }
            }

            function A() {
                a.modal && b('<div class="b-modal ' + e + '"></div>').css({
                    backgroundColor: a.modalColor,
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    opacity: 0,
                    zIndex: a.zIndex + t
                }).appendTo(a.appendTo).fadeTo(a.speed, a.opacity);
                D();
                c.data("bPopup", a).data("id", e).css({
                    left: "slideIn" == a.transition || "slideBack" == a.transition ? "slideBack" == a.transition ? g.scrollLeft() + u : -1 * (v + s) : l(!(!a.follow[0] && m || f)),
                    position: a.positionStyle || "absolute",
                    top: "slideDown" == a.transition || "slideUp" == a.transition ? "slideUp" == a.transition ? g.scrollTop() + w : x + -1 * r : n(!(!a.follow[1] && p || f)),
                        "z-index": a.zIndex + t + 1
                }).each(function () {
                    a.appending && b(this).appendTo(a.appendTo)
                });
                H(!0)
            }

            function q() {
                a.modal && b(".b-modal." + c.data("id")).fadeTo(a.speed, 0, function () {
                    b(this).remove()
                });
                a.scrollBar || b("html").css("overflow", "auto");
                b(".b-modal." + e).unbind("click");
                g.unbind("keydown." + e);
                d.unbind("." + e).data("bPopup", 0 < d.data("bPopup") - 1 ? d.data("bPopup") - 1 : null);
                c.undelegate(".bClose, ." + a.closeClass, "click." + e, q).data("bPopup", null);
                H();
                return !1
            }

            function G(h) {
                var b = h.width(),
                    e = h.height(),
                    d = {};
                a.contentContainer.css({
                    height: e,
                    width: b
                });
                e >= c.height() && (d.height = c.height());
                b >= c.width() && (d.width = c.width());
                r = c.outerHeight(!0);
                s = c.outerWidth(!0);
                D();
                a.contentContainer.css({
                    height: "auto",
                    width: "auto"
                });
                d.left = l(!(!a.follow[0] && m || f));
                d.top = n(!(!a.follow[1] && p || f));
                c.animate(d, 250, function () {
                    h.show();
                    B = E()
                })
            }

            function L() {
                d.data("bPopup", t);
                c.delegate(".bClose, ." + a.closeClass, "click." + e, q);
                a.modalClose && b(".b-modal." + e).css("cursor", "pointer").bind("click", q);
                M || !a.follow[0] && !a.follow[1] || d.bind("scroll." + e, function () {
                    B && c.dequeue().animate({
                        left: a.follow[0] ? l(!f) : "auto",
                        top: a.follow[1] ? n(!f) : "auto"
                    }, a.followSpeed, a.followEasing)
                }).bind("resize." + e, function () {
                    w = y.innerHeight || d.height();
                    u = y.innerWidth || d.width();
                    if (B = E()) clearTimeout(I), I = setTimeout(function () {
                        D();
                        c.dequeue().each(function () {
                            f ? b(this).css({
                                left: v,
                                top: x
                            }) : b(this).animate({
                                left: a.follow[0] ? l(!0) : "auto",
                                top: a.follow[1] ? n(!0) : "auto"
                            }, a.followSpeed, a.followEasing)
                        })
                    }, 50)
                });
                a.escClose && g.bind("keydown." + e, function (a) {
                    27 == a.which && q()
                })
            }

            function H(b) {
                function d(e) {
                    c.css({
                        display: "block",
                        opacity: 1
                    }).animate(e, a.speed, a.easing, function () {
                        J(b)
                    })
                }
                switch (b ? a.transition : a.transitionClose || a.transition) {
                    case "slideIn":
                        d({
                            left: b ? l(!(!a.follow[0] && m || f)) : g.scrollLeft() - (s || c.outerWidth(!0)) - C
                        });
                        break;
                    case "slideBack":
                        d({
                            left: b ? l(!(!a.follow[0] && m || f)) : g.scrollLeft() + u + C
                        });
                        break;
                    case "slideDown":
                        d({
                            top: b ? n(!(!a.follow[1] && p || f)) : g.scrollTop() - (r || c.outerHeight(!0)) - C
                        });
                        break;
                    case "slideUp":
                        d({
                            top: b ? n(!(!a.follow[1] && p || f)) : g.scrollTop() + w + C
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        c.stop().fadeTo(a.speed, b ? 1 : 0, function () {
                            J(b)
                        })
                }
            }

            function J(b) {
                b ? (L(), k(F), a.autoClose && setTimeout(q, a.autoClose)) : (c.hide(), k(a.onClose), a.loadUrl && (a.contentContainer.empty(), c.css({
                    height: "auto",
                    width: "auto"
                })))
            }

            function l(a) {
                return a ? v + g.scrollLeft() : v
            }

            function n(a) {
                return a ? x + g.scrollTop() : x
            }

            function k(a) {
                b.isFunction(a) && a.call(c)
            }

            function D() {
                x = p ? a.position[1] : Math.max(0, (w - c.outerHeight(!0)) / 2 - a.amsl);
                v = m ? a.position[0] : (u - c.outerWidth(!0)) / 2;
                B = E()
            }

            function E() {
                return w > c.outerHeight(!0) && u > c.outerWidth(!0)
            }
            b.isFunction(z) && (F = z, z = null);
            var a = b.extend({}, b.fn.bPopup.defaults, z);
            a.scrollBar || b("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
            var c = this,
                g = b(document),
                y = window,
                d = b(y),
                w = y.innerHeight || d.height(),
                u = y.innerWidth || d.width(),
                M = /OS 6(_\d)+/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
                C = 200,
                t = 0,
                e, B, p, m, f, x, v, r, s, I;
            c.close = function () {
                a = this.data("bPopup");
                e = "__b-popup" + d.data("bPopup") + "__";
                q()
            };
            return c.each(function () {
                b(this).data("bPopup") || (k(a.onOpen), t = (d.data("bPopup") || 0) + 1, e = "__b-popup" + t + "__", p = "auto" !== a.position[1], m = "auto" !== a.position[0], f = "fixed" === a.positionStyle, r = c.outerHeight(!0), s = c.outerWidth(!0), a.loadUrl ? K() : A())
            })
        };
        b.fn.bPopup.defaults = {
            amsl: 50,
            appending: !0,
            appendTo: "body",
            autoClose: !1,
            closeClass: "b-close",
            content: "ajax",
            contentContainer: !1,
            easing: "swing",
            escClose: !0,
            follow: [!0, !0],
            followEasing: "swing",
            followSpeed: 500,
            iframeAttr: 'scrolling="no" frameborder="0"',
            loadCallback: !1,
            loadData: !1,
            loadUrl: !1,
            modal: !0,
            modalClose: !0,
            modalColor: "#000",
            onClose: !1,
            onOpen: !1,
            opacity: 0.7,
            position: ["auto", "auto"],
            positionStyle: "absolute",
            scrollBar: !0,
            speed: 250,
            transition: "fadeIn",
            transitionClose: !1,
            zIndex: 9997
        }

    })(jQuery);
```

=========================================================================
Here I've created a **JSFiddle** link for all the code that is needed: https://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/13617/

Comment: Hiding the video container isn't the same as stopping it playing. It's still there, still playing, so you still get sound from it.

Comment: I know that Todd, knowing it still don't resolve the problem as to finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

obviously this modal is loading the video playing it, then when it's closed it's just being hidden, it's still in the DOM.  You need to find a way of destroying this code that is brought into the DOM.   You could use something like jQuery remove.

Comment: Yes Chris H, but the problem is that I don't even know how to do that or find the dome. I am not very good with jquery. :(

Comment: But thank you anyway for the tip :) I do appreciate it so much .

Comment: Well, thank you everyone for NOT helping me. Such a great place to be here??!! Definately will find another place since here you never get help with an issue that in fact could resolve other people problems.

Comment: Fair enough! Nobody works for free. Why should someone help?!, Why this website even exist?! I dont know.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here's how I got around it:

https://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/14789/

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
<button id="my-button"> Play video </button>
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up" data-iframe-code="<iframe width='450' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ev4zBCBEELQ' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"> 
    <a class="b-close"> x <a/>
</div><!-- end of element_to_pop_up id -->
```

What I changed:

- I took the iFrame code out of the DOM, and put it somewhere that it can be reused as often as we'd like. A data attribute probably isn't the best place to put it, but I was short on time and ideas. Comment if you can think of something better.

**JS (Just the bPopup bit):**

```
// Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    onOpen: function(){
        $(this).append( $( $(this).data('iframe-code') ) );
    },
    onClose:function(){
        $(this).find('iframe').remove();
    }
});
```

What I changed:

- Added an onOpen event to bPopup. When the popup opens, the iframe code gets added to the #element_to_pop_up div.
- Added an onClose event, When the popup is closed, the iframe is deleted. Because it can't play in the background if it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a very big JS Code which I am not able to understand, just use this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v95eg4h1/

I am using jQuery Library(1.11.0)

```js
$(function(){
    $("#showPopup").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".bg").toggle();
        $(".popup").toggle();
    });
    
$(".close").click(function() {
    $('.modal').hide();
    $("#arsha_video").attr('src','');
    
       var video = $("#player").attr("src");
        $("#player").attr("src","");
        $("#player").attr("src",video);

});

    
    $("body").click(function(){
        $(".bg").toggle();
        $(".popup").hide();
           var video = $("#player").attr("src");
        $("#player").attr("src","");
        $("#player").attr("src",video);
    });
});
```

```css
.popup{
   background-color:#E6E9F2;
   position:absolute;
   min-height:auto;
   width:auto;
   border: solid 2px #B9EAF0;
   z-index: 1002;
}

.bg {
   background-color:#111;
   opacity: 0.65;
   position:absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
   min-height:100%;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="showPopup">CLICK</a>

<div class="bg" style="display:none"></div>

<div class="popup" style="display:none">
     <a class=".close"> x <a/>
<iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ev4zBCBEELQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't mind to change the approach then you can try **[colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)**. it is very good with popup with responsive design and easy to implement.
[youtubevideo in iframe](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/)